# Problems with two monitors and Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 19.10

I have just bough a new PC with NVIDIA graphics, and can't make a freshly installed Ubuntu 19.10 work with dual monitors properly. I installed the nNVIDIA  driver (435) and It works fine for a few minutes, then both monitors goes black and my system crashes every single time, however it works perfectly fine with one monitor.

If I switch to Nouveau I stuck in a login loop. However if I switch to Wayland at the login screen, everything seems to work fine.

My main problem is that I would like to use my PC for gaming every now and then, so I would like to make the two monitors work with the NVIDIA driver, but right now I am out of ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem. The problem was that I used two HDMI to VGA adapter for both monitors. Now with 1 HDMI to VGA, and 1 HDMI to DVI-D it works fine. Lesson: don't use two VGA adapter.